# Placing Button and TextView on ActionBar with home button

Tags: java, android

I need home button and 2 views to appear on my ActionBar. My textView is not exactly where it should be placed and home button disappears. Here is what I get:
[image]

This is what I need:
[image]

Code I used:

```
package com.example.trythis;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
public class BeginGameActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_try);

    }

     @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
        {
            switch (item.getItemId()) 
            {
            case android.R.id.home:
                if(NavUtils.getParentActivityName(this) != null)
                {
                    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }



     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

            android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setTitle("Назад");
            actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);

            return true;
        }



}
```

main_try.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/main_container" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">


    </LinearLayout> 
 </RelativeLayout>
```

actionbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        >
        <TextView 

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/minesLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/minesLeftCounter"
            android:text="asd"      />

        <Button
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/refresh_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/refresh" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/minesLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/minesLeft" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

What do I need to change? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your home `Button` is disappearing because of the following line:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Change the argument to `true`.

Your layout just needed a few centering tweaks here and there. Also, when you set a custom `View` on the `ActionBar`, the title no longer appears, so we can simply add another `TextView` to the custom `View` to display the title.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Назад" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/minesLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/minesLeftCounter"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/minesLeft" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/minesLeftCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/refresh_button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="asd" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/refresh_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="@string/refresh" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @БейбутТукибаев I had forgotten that the title View is hidden when you set a custom View on the ActionBar. I've edited my answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use Toolbar instead of Actionbar:

1- Create a new xml file with "tool_bar.xml" and add this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="my Button"
    />
```

2 - Go to your main_try.xml and add the code below to include it:

```
<include android:id="@+id/toolbar" layout="@layout/bar"/>
```

3 - In BigenGameActivity.java Change this `extends Activity` to be `extends AppCompatActivity`

4 -  add this into your onCreate method:

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and here's the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZEeU.png)